# Load jar file contained within another jar file not working

Tags: java, resources, classloader

I've been playing around with loading jar files dynamically and I can't get this to work.  I have a jar file (resource.jar) in my source folder of Eclipse so it's in the classpath.  I'm trying to get it as a resource to load an applet, add it to a jframe, and run it.  This isn't working for some unknown reason to myself.  This is the code I'm trying.

```
URL jarURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resource.jar");
ClassLoader urlLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{jarURL});
applet = (Applet) urlLoader.loadClass("test.TestClassApplet").newInstance();
jframe.add(applet);
applet.init();
applet.start();
```

I get no error when I try to get the resource, the error is when I load the class.  I get a ClassNotFoundException, even though the class IS in the jar file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URLClassLoader is designed to be used for loading classes and resources that are accessed by searching a set of URLs. It won't extract the class in the jar file for you.

See [JarClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/jarclassloader.html) tutorial.

Comment: Also please see this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime